# Divison in modular arithmetic

Tags: modular-arithmetic

I have just read that 3x congruent to 12 modulo 15 is equivalent to x congruent to 4 modulo 5. However, I thought division could only be done in modular equations if gcd(a,n)=1 but in this case, gcd(3,15)=3. Could someone please explain to me why these are equivalent and if my understanding is correct. Thanks

Comment: Please use MathJax. [Here's a tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/742).

Comment: $3x\equiv 12\pmod{\!15}\Rightarrow x\equiv 4\pmod{\!5}\,$ is not division by $\,3\,$ (done $\!\bmod 15)$ because the modulus has has changed from $\,15\,$ to $\,5.\,$ By convention, *operations* (like addition, multiplication and division) denote maps whose arguments and result all lie in the *same* number system (ring), here $\,\Bbb Z_{15} = \Bbb Z\bmod 15.\,$ See the linked dupes for general results on modular division (cancellation).

Answer (score 0):

You're both right! These are special cases of the following general result:
$$
aj \equiv ak \pmod n \qquad\text{if and only if}\qquad j \equiv k \pmod{\frac n{\gcd(a,n)}}.
$$
Your assertion is the case where $\gcd(a,n)=1$; the example you read deals with the case $\gcd(a,n)=a$.

Comment: Please strive not to post more (dupe) answers to dupes of FAQs, cf. recent site policy announcement [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/33508/242).

Comment: You're right :)